# Reverse SSH Tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling, load-balancing, gitlab

I have a gitlab server on my local network and a server that I can ssh to from outside my network.

Is there a way I can configure the server, that I can SSH into, so that when I use:

`ssh git@git.mypublicserver.com`

It sends that to the Gitlab server on the local network? Kind of like an Nginx reverse proxy but with ssh.

#### Edit:

I've been looking around and I found something [here](https://docs.pivotal.io/gitlab/ssh.html) that looks like what I want.

> #### Access via Load Balancer
>
> If you want to provide a more standard git experience you can manually  > set up and configure an external load balancer to point to a given
> GitLab node. This should route traffic from port 22 to port 2222 on the > GitLab node. You can then point a DNS record at the load balancer.

This looks like what I am trying to do, but how do I accomplish this?

#### Edit 2:

Here is an image that can hopefully clarify what I am trying to do.

(Those red lines should be going through the internet too.)

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Look at the `-L` option to `ssh`.

Comment: is this done on the client side, and if so is there a way to not do that and make the public server tunnel into the local server based on the domain name?

Comment: Look up "ssh proxycommand". Though I'm not sure if there's some added complication here.

Comment: Do you want to forward all `ssh` connections to `mypublicserver.com` to the internal gitlab server? Or do you want to only forward some connections? Based on what criteria?

Comment: I want to do it based off of domain. e.g. `ssh username@git.mypublicserver.com` would be sent to the internal server and `ssh username@mypublicserver.com` would go to the public server. (See edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP servers like nginx are able to proxy based on the hostname because it is sent in the HTTP/1.1 Host header of the request. SSH does not have this concept of virtual hosts, the client not send the hostname at all.

You have three options:

- Use port forwarding to make your gitlab server directly available.
- Make your gitlab server available through an (additional) IPv4 or IPv6 address.
- Create a SSH tunnel into your network and proxy the SSH connection to your git server through this tunnel.

### Port forwarding

This is probably the easiest approach that does interfere with the "public server". Setup your gateway to forward port 2222 to 192.168.2.26:22. Then use the `ssh -p2222 git@git.example.com` to connect. For `git`, use URLs like `ssh://git@git.example.com:2222/repo.git`.

Alternatively, you can just use `ssh://git@git.example.com/repo.git` or `git@git.example.git:repo.git` if you create a `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
Host git.example.com
    Port 2222
```

### Additional IPv4 or IPv6 address

If you have a home network, getting an IPv4 address is probably impossible, but some business providers do it. If your network supports IPv6 (end-to-end), then you can just use normal routing without nasty proxying or NAT hackery.

### SSH tunnel

You can use the `ProxyCommand` option to specify the command that proxies the SSH connection to `git.example.com`. In your case, the "public server" is the proxy, so the command should be connecting to that server.

Let's start with the configuration snippet for `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host git.example.com
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p username@example.com
```

In this snippet the `-W %h:%p` option will be expanded to `-W git.example.com:22` and redirect standard input and output to said host (git.example.com). This enables your local SSH client to speak with your gitlab server. You can again use any URL like `git@git.example.com:repo.git`, the proxy will be transparant to the git client.

Comment: This may not be in the scope of this question but, how does Github or Gitlab do it? Don't you push to a single github server/load balancer that proxies/tunnels/somethings you to the appropriate server?

Comment: It looks like Gitlab uses haproxy and that cannot decipher who traffic is supposed to go to, but decides *itself* where traffic should go, I will try your port forwarding solution, thank you for your help.

Comment: @agustaf I don't know how they do it, but I can imagine that they just forward based on the TCP flows, completely agnostic of the SSH protocol which delegates the computational complexity.

Comment: My gateway did not let me forward port 2222 to 22 so I ended up doing the same thing with iptables like this: `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j REDIRECT --to-port 22`

Comment: @agustaf You could also add `Port 2222` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for the same effect.